# False Positives in Cypress-axe Plugin for Accessibility Testing

Tags: accessibility, cypress, storybook

I am running accessibility testing using the cypress-axe plugin with cypress and storybook. The `cypress-axe` plugin continually gives false positives when having made the required changes.

The false positive is for page-has-heading-one but I clearly have a h1 element present in the screenshot.

[False Positive screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bIAf.png)

Cypress version: 6.1

cypress-axe version: 0.12.0

Here's the html for the element in question:

```
<div role="main"class="example-slider">
  <h1 role="banner">Slider</h1>
    <mat-slider 
      min="1"
      max="50"
      step="0.5"
      themePalette="primary"
      id="slide"
      value="1.5"
      aria-label="slider"
      role="contentinfo"
      >
    </mat-slider>
  </div>
```

Thank you ahead of time if anyone can help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a false positive.

The second you gave the `<h1>` a `role` you changed it's semantic meaning.

[`role="banner"` is effectively the same as `<header>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Banner_role) in HTML5, so you have changed your `<h1>` into a `<header>` element as far as a computer and assistive technology is concerned.

Remove that `role="banner"` from your `<h1>` and it will work as expected (and be semantically correct).

Also while you are tidying things up `<div role="main"` is the same as `<main>`, you should always try to use semantically correct native HTML elements where you can as they will make your mark-up cleaner and they have wider support.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will be sure to keep that in mind moving forward with accessibility.

Comment: Not a problem at all, good luck with your project(s)! FYI you can click the tick icon to accept this answer if it fixed your problem.